# cannot install yesod

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, haskell-platform, cabal-install

I follow installation steps given on http://www.yesodweb.com/book/TXKGPHUZXDLYRGF

the command "cabal install alex happy" fails with the error below.

what is wrong? I am totally new. this is my first attempt to install yesod. I am on windows xp.

thanks for any help

Konstantin

`d:>cabal install alex happy
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Couldn't read cabal file "bytestring\0.9.2.0\bytestring.cabal"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hackage was triggering a bug in cabal but that has been addressed.  Do a `cabal update` and things should build now.

Comment: thanks. that fixed it. I just installed Haskell Platform today and apparently it did not have the latest "cabal". now I am getting an error saying that I need Perl to be able to install "alex". this is ironic. For web development I am trying to switch to a language that I find superior to Perl and I still have to drag Perl with me. :)